# Foundation Joyride throwing error for unknown reason in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation, zurb-joyride

So I am using Foundation for a website I am building, all is good and love using foundation, but in Firefox 28.0 on a Windows machine I am getting an error from JQuery which is related to Joyride.

I am not using Joyride anywhere within the site so I really don't understand why this error is happening, and it seems to only happen in FF.

I have attached the error in a code block, you will notice "Gotham" in there, Gotham is the custom font that I am using, but it is not referenced in any HTML anywhere, just in CSS so I don't understand where this is coming from.

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [data-"Gotham"-joyride]            jquery....min.js (line 2)

...turn function(b){return db(a,b).length>0}}),contains:fb(function(a){return funct...
```

Hope you guys can help, let me know if you need any more code or anything.

Cheers, 
Luke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after much playing around I finally found out what was causing this issue.

I was using the following code:

```
* {
  font-family: "Gotham";
}
```

Removing this code solved the problem.

Don't ask me how, or why because I do not know, all I can think is that because `*` is a global selector it was targeting something it shouldn't be and was causing this issue.

Strange one.

This may or may not solve the problem for others as I noticed that other people had different solutions to this issue or similar issues.